# Incompatible css changes on children on parent hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code :

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.container:hover .logo {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.container:hover .picture {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element-header">
    <div class="element">Foo</div>
    <div class="element">Bar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader">&nbsp;</div>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt="" class="picture">
</div>
```

When .container is hovered, I want .logo to be at opacity:1 and .picture to be at filter: brightness(0.7).

When a try to apply those properties one-by-one at .container hover, each is working. But when both are set-up, only the filter one is working.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I guess a part of the question got lost ! Weird, I am about to rewrite it.

Comment: i posted answer b4 i saw the edited question.. just re-reading now. yep that works

Comment: I enlarged the logo to 100px- it was hard to gauge whether it was working (or even see it!) at 30px wide..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the position to `relative` instead of `absolute`, both images will display. As the code stood, one image was getting lost. (I substituted my own images in and added a picture class to size the image)

The transition works fine though!

Try below:

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  //height:auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.picture {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.container:hover .logo {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.container:hover .picture {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element-header">
    <div class="element">Foo</div>
    <div class="element">Bar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="loader">&nbsp;</div>
  <img src="https://www.dcu.ie/sites/default/files/afu_logo2_1.jpg" alt="agefriendly" class="logo">
  <img src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" class="picture">
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0mbvqanf/)

Comment: Thank you Rachel ! Intersting behaviour to see the positionning cause trouble only on hover.

Comment: @Guillaume always happy to help! :)

Comment: @Guillaume the fact that there was no picture class also contributed though (that's unless you had css for it but didn't  post it).. good to note.. if you don't put a size to the picture then they could display differently such as here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0mbvqanf/3/  (the transition will still work but the alignment will be different) - just a tip!